# Is there a way to export excel from adf table where some columns of the excel will be readonly?

Tags: excel, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I created a export adf read-only table to excel but I couldn't find a solution where I can make some of the columns of the excel uneditable.

my code is as follows

```
<af:commandButton text="Download Excel" id="cb3">
                      <af:setPropertyListener from="true"
                                              to="#{pageFlowScope.hideTheseColumnsInExcel}"
                                              type="action"/>
                      <af:exportCollectionActionListener type="excelHTML"
                                                         exportedId="t1"
                                                         filename="emtiaz.xls"
                                                         title="Emtiaz"/>
                      <af:setPropertyListener from="false"
                                              to="#{pageFlowScope.hideTheseColumnsInExcel}"
                                              type="action"/>
</af:commandButton>
```

The above code is the button and the property listeners i used to select the specific columns.

Comment: I don't think this can be done from the ADF export. You may need to use Apache POI and do it programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

ExportCollection doesn't give you this level of control.
You can choose to use ADF Desktop Integration which will let you control this:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/adf/overview/index-085534.html

Answer (score 0):

you need to set format in excel file , check the following URL
http://andrejusb.blogspot.com/2016/05/adf-hidden-gem-export-collection.html

if you need to hide column when export table to excel file 
kindly find the following code

download button :-

```
<af:commandButton text="#{appviewcontrollerbundle.exportExcel}"
                            id="cmi2" styleClass="btn-action"
                            disabled="#{bindings.ChatbotQuestionAnswerView1.estimatedRowCount == 0}"
                            rendered="#{sessionScope.channel ne 'MobileApp'}">
            <af:setPropertyListener from="1"  to="#{pageFlowScope.hideTheseColumnsInExcel}" type="action"/>
            <af:exportCollectionActionListener exportedId="t1"
                                               type="excelHTML" 
                                               filename="ChatBot.xls"
                                               title="Chatbot_Questions"/>     
            <af:setPropertyListener from="2" to="#{pageFlowScope.hideTheseColumnsInExcel}" type="action"/>
          </af:commandButton>
```

Unwanted column to show in excel file :-

```
<af:column sortable="false" rendered="#{ pageFlowScope.hideTheseColumnsInExcel eq null or  pageFlowScope.hideTheseColumnsInExcel eq '2'}" partialTriggers="::cmi2" 
               headerText="delete" id="c7"
               noWrap="false" width="55" align="center">
      <af:commandLink action="delete" immediate="true"  text="delete" id="cb4" styleClass="btn-action" >
        <af:showPopupBehavior popupId="::p1" triggerType="action"/>
      </af:commandLink>
    </af:column>
```